# How to search over all fields and return every document containing that search in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-6

I have a problem regarding searching in elasticsearch.
I have a index with multiple documents with several fields. I want to be able to search over all the fields running a query and want it to return all the documents that contains the value specified in the query. I Found that using `simple_query_string` worked well for this. However, it does not return consistent results. In my index I have documents with several fields that contain dates. For example:

```
"revisionDate" : "2008-01-01T00:00:00",
"projectSmirCreationDate" : "2008-07-01T00:00:00",
"changedDate" : "1971-01-01T00:00:00",
"dueDate" : "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
```

Those are just a few examples, however when I index for example:

```
GET new_document-20_v2/_search
{
  "size": 1000, 
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "2008"
    }
  }
}
```

It only returns two documents, this is a problem because I have much more documents than just two that contains the value "2008" in their fields.

I also have problem searching file names.
In my index there are fields that contain fileNames like this:

```
"fileName" : "testPDF.pdf",
"fileName" : "demo.pdf",
"fileName" : "demo.txt",
```

When i query:

```
GET new_document-20_v2/_search
{
  "size": 1000, 
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "demo"
    }
  }
}
```

**I get no results**
But if i query:

```
GET new_document-20_v2/_search
{
  "size": 1000, 
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string" : {
        "query": "demo.txt"
    }
  }
}
```

I get the proper result.

Is there any better way to search across all documents and fields than I did? I want it to return all the document matching the query and not just two or zero.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share your index mapping ?

Comment: if you don't specify a field `multi_match` (and your index doesn't have a default search field set) it will search all searchable fields [multi_match docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#query-dsl-multi-match-query)

Comment: @ESCoder the mapping is a bit large so here is a "justpaste.it" link https://jpst.it/2uuTT

Comment: @Nate Using ```multi_match``` still only returns two documents when querying "2008"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch uses a standard analyzer if no analyzer is specified. Since no analyzer is specified on `"fileName"`, `demo.txt` gets tokenized to

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "demo.txt",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Now when you are searching for `demo` it will not give any result, but searching for `demo.txt` will give the result.

---

You can instead use a [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) to search for a document having `demo` in `fileName`

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "fileName": {
        "value": "demo*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67303015",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "fileName": "demo.pdf"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67303015",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "fileName": "demo.txt"
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

Since `revisionDate`, `projectSmirCreationDate`, `changedDate`, `dueDate` are all of type `date`, so you cannot do a partial search on these dates.

You can use [multi-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html), to add one more field (of `text` type) in the above fields. Modify your index mapping as shown below

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "changedDate": {
        "type": "date",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      },
      "projectSmirCreationDate": {
        "type": "date",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      },
      "dueDate": {
        "type": "date",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      },
      "revisionDate": {
        "type": "date",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "revisionDate": "2008-02-01T00:00:00",
  "projectSmirCreationDate": "2008-02-01T00:00:00",
  "changedDate": "1971-01-01T00:00:00",
  "dueDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
}
{
  "revisionDate": "2008-01-01T00:00:00",
  "projectSmirCreationDate": "2008-07-01T00:00:00",
  "changedDate": "1971-01-01T00:00:00",
  "dueDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "2008"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67303015",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "revisionDate": "2008-01-01T00:00:00",
          "projectSmirCreationDate": "2008-07-01T00:00:00",
          "changedDate": "1971-01-01T00:00:00",
          "dueDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67303015",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.18232156,
        "_source": {
          "revisionDate": "2008-02-01T00:00:00",
          "projectSmirCreationDate": "2008-02-01T00:00:00",
          "changedDate": "1971-01-01T00:00:00",
          "dueDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @Sander Marx please go through the above answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: After modifying my index mapping as you showed it worked like i want it to! Thank you so much!